# ¿Como evito que al ingresar un caracter en lugar de un numero marque error?

Tags: python

Al inicio si el usuario ingrese su salario y pone una letra en lugar me marca error ya que no puede convertir strings a floats que puedo hacer para que si el usuario hace eso le diga su error y se repita la opción

```
salir=0
    while salir==0:
        salario=float(input('Ingrese su salario'))

        if salario<4000 and salario>0:
            aumento = salario*0.15
            print(aumento)


        else:
            aumento = salario*0.08
            print(aumento)

        terminar=input("salir s/n")

        if terminar=="s":
                 salir=1
        else:
                 salir=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Traté de documentar todo el código para hacerlo lo más entendible posible.

```
salir = False  # Modifique el tipo de la variable 'salir' para
               # que, al ser un booleano, se pueda entender rapidamente 
               # y facilmente para que sirve 
               #                             |
               #                             |
while not salir:  # aqui. <------------------| "Mientras no salir :)"
    try:
        salario = float(raw_input('Ingrese su salario: '))  # raw_input para leer la cadena 
                                                            # y poder atrapar el error.|
        # Como se comento en los comentarios, en caso de que estes utilizando python 3 |
        # en lugar de 'raw_input()' pon 'input()'. De la misma manera en la parte de   |
        # mas abajo en el codigo.                                                       
    except ValueError:  # Este error. <------------------------------------------------|
        print("Ingresa solo numeros.")
        # Y al atraparlo, no se termina el ciclo, solo se entra a este nivel y no se
        # ejecuta el código del bloque else.
    else:  # Si no entra al error, entonces hace las operaciones definidas.
        if salario < 4000 and salario > 0:
            aumento = salario*0.15
            print(aumento)
        else:
            aumento = salario*0.08
            print(aumento)
    finally:  # Entre o no entre al error, siempre se le va a preguntar
              # al usuario si desea continuar.
        terminar = ''
        while terminar.lower() not in ['s','n']:  # Anadi esto para forzar al usuario a que escriba
                                                  # 's' o 'n'.
            terminar = raw_input("Salir? (s/n): ")
            salir = True if terminar.lower() == 's' else False
```

Cuya ejecución da algo de la forma.

```
$ python salario.py
Ingrese su salario: 9
1.35
Salir? (s/n): n
Ingrese su salario: as
Ingresa solo numeros.
Salir? (s/n): 333333
Salir? (s/n): n
Ingrese su salario: 12341234
987298.72
Salir? (s/n): s
```

En resumen, la respuesta a tu pregunta está dada por el uso de un `except` para atrapar un `ValueError` generado por la conversión fallida de una cadena a un float, y esta cadena se va a recibir, sin evaluar, con `raw_input`.

Comment: La sintaxis del código de la pregunta sugiere que está usando pyrhon3. En esta versión no hay raw_input porque input us devuelve siempre cadena

Comment: Buen punto, gracias. Ya quedó comentado.